# set jquery default animation speed

Tags: jquery

I cannot find any documentation. All I want to do it set jQuerys default animation speed. Something like this:

```
 $.setDefaultAnimationSpeed = 5000; //does not work

 $('elem').fadeIn(); // takes 5 seconds
 $('elem').animate({
     foo : bar
 }); // also takes 5 seconds
```

Thanks folks!

Comment: I wrote a dumby command. $.setDefaultAnimationSpeed is not a real thing.

Comment: Trying to set $.setDefaultAnimationSpeed doesn't work because jQuery's default animation speed doesn't trigger off such a property (nor any property for that matter that I know of). Instead, you should use the method @dku.rajkumar has provided as it is the most commonly used method of setting a "global" animation speed that you can use throughout your jQuery script.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
$.fx.speeds._default = 1000; // change to whatever your desired speed
```

or

```
$.fx.speeds.jojo = 1000; // adds your own speed object to jqueryspeed
```

Reference: https://learn.jquery.com/effects/intro-to-effects/#jquery-fx

Answer (score -2):

i dont think there is any such thing in jquery but you can try something like this

```
 defaultAnimationSpeed = 5000;  // declare a global variable

 $('elem').fadeIn(defaultAnimationSpeed); 
 $('elem').animate({foo : bar}, defaultAnimationSpeed);
```

So that it will be applicable wherever it is used and also you can change it very easily. you need not change everywhere in animation.

Comment: The above answer is really good.. but why downvote to my answer, Pls mind giving reason ???

Comment: because its not accurate, and not the right answer. I down voted it so others will not be mislead.

Comment: Also downvotes don't take of 17 points. I moved the green check to a better answer.

Comment: well i understand that.. you moved green that was fair but it didnt deserve downvote... anyway no issue as your wish :)

Comment: your answer is just wrong. You can do it with jquery.

Comment: The user asked how to override the default. You say you don't think there is any such thing (there is), and then suggest that they do what they're trying to do a different way.